# css color declaration failing on android device, works in normal browsers

Tags: android, css

I have a simple html char in a span like so:

```
<span class="requiredInd">&nbsp; &diams;</span>
```

with simple css:

```
color: red;
```

Which makes a red diamond shape and works fine on desktop browsers.

On my android device (Galaxy S6 with Chrome browser) the diamond does not get the color. It is gray and somewhat 3d stylized.

I have tried adding -webkit-appearance: none; but it made no difference. What else should I be trying here?

Comment: have you tried a hex value for your color?

Comment: I have now, that also fails.

Comment: If the shape is not correct, changing it to either hex `&#x2666;` or decimal `&#9830;` HTML entitity should do it. If the color does not apply, you need to find a way to inspect the shape on your device and see what applies. It's possible that the device or the browser apply a stronger selector on it. They tend to do this in the name of *usability* and *accesibility*. Using `!important` will, probably, fix your problem, but knowing the exact specificity of the applied selector and overriding it is the proper solution. What's your current selector?

Comment: !important has not fixed the problem. As for a selector, I'm now applying the style inline like <span style="..."> still to no avail. I'll look into inspecting the element on the device, no idea how to make that happen.